# How do I get a user account out of "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD" mode when I don't have a user session recorded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are using AWS Cognito CLI (cognito-idp), and our dev & staging environments are frequently iterating, and as such we sometimes have a user account entering the `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` state - and yet we don't have the session info we need to trigger the password change, nor can we seem to then trigger another "reset".

Is there a way to toggle the state out of `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`, or a way to get the session token needed to change the password ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the *old/temporary* password of that user which is in FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD state?

If yes, then you could use that same password to authenticate, which would return a challenge called `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED`. You can then use this session id, to make a subsequent call to reset the password.

Steps:

1. Call **admin-initate-auth** with **--auth-flow** as "**ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH**" with old password.
2. Response should have challenge as `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED`. Save the session id.
3. Call **admin-respond-to-auth-challenge** with the above value for **--challenge-name** and new password.